# Ecto join on `not equal` bug

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have two schemas like this:

```
schema "projects" do
  field :title, :string
  field :is_shared, :boolean
  timestamps()
end

schema "cards" do
  field :title, :string
  field :type, :string
  belongs_to(:project, Project)
end
```

now I want to find the cards  of the project that not shared.

I use this query:

```
    from(c0 in Card,
      join:
        p1 in subquery(
          from p0 in Project,
            where: p0.is_shared == false,
            select: p0.id
        ),
      on: c0.project_id != p1.id,
      where: c0.type == "golden"
    )
```

but It gives me a Postgrex error:

```
Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.494.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.527.0> timed out because it queued and checked out the connection for longer than 15000ms
```

But when I use the raw sql that debug print, there's no problem.

```sql
SELECT c0."id",
       c0."title",
       c0."inserted_at",
       c0."updated_at"
FROM "cards" AS c0
         INNER JOIN (SELECT p0."id" AS "id" FROM "projects" AS p0 WHERE (p0."is_shared" = FALSE)) AS s1
                    ON c0."project_id" != s1."id"
WHERE (c0."type" = 'golden')
```

the raw sql above is very fast. It only cost 100-200 ms.

Comment: What code do you run that raises? What code do you run that succeeds?

Comment: timeout error, and I run that sql succeed by psql .

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to left join and inserting null Project id to do an excluding join, like this:

```
from(c0 in Card,
left_join: p1 in Project,
on: c0.project_id ==  p1.id,
where: is_nil(p1.id) and c0.type == "golden" and p1.is_shared == false,
select: c0)
```

also, you dont need ^ when dealing with == string in ecto.

Could be that your query is trying to join one ID on every different ID, which means if you are doing with two tables of 10,000 rows each, you would end up with almost 100,000,000 rows. Not sure why that doesnt happen on your raw sql.

Also, if you want to "find the cards of the project that not shared.", you should do a basic join, not an excluding one, like this:

```
from(c0 in Card,
join: p1 in Project,
on: c0.project_id == p1.id,
where: c0.type == "golden" and p1.is_shared == false,
select: c0)
```

Comment: Yes, Finally I used left_join, but I don't know why ecto have this bug. And because my shared projects records are very huge, So I need to exclude the not shared. excluding can use the index.

Comment: Isn't p1.is_shared == false sufficient for excluding the not shared? Maybe i am missing something. Also, what do you get when doing count(*) at your raw psql and at your ecto query?